# Creating a table that is a sub query of another table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a large table of staff data and I would like create tables on other worksheets with filtered sets of data from the main data set.  I am experienced in writing extensive VBA macros and could accomplish what I want with a database and SQL is minutes but I feel like I'm going after an Ant hill with a boot.

I tried doing it with a pivot table, however I am inexperienced with pivot tables and could not get results that I'm happy with.

The large staff data set contains things such as start date, current department, specialist skill sets etc. (The normal things you'd expect).

I'd like to create dynamic table on other worksheets that for instance show all staff that work in X department or all staff that have Y specialist skill.  Obviously I want the worksheet tables to update when data is changed or added on the main data set.

Am I right in thinking there is a simple solution here or do I need to go after it using an actual DB?

Comment: It might be better to create a Custom View, rather than a table. See http://excelunplugged.com/2015/03/10/custom-views-or-excel-tables-sophies-choice-in-excel/

Comment: Please share some sample data along with criteria, then I'll show you few methods to filter records in another Sheet.

Comment: @RajeshS unfortunately the worksheet has a lot of confidential information that I would have to remove to provide sample data (even in the column headings etc.).  It is essentially just a generic employee database with all the normal fields you'd expect.  `Name   EmployeeNo   StartDate   Gender   Title   CurrentDepartment   DepartmentStartDate` etc etc.  All formatted in an excel table that can be filtered.

Comment: Essentially if I was using SQL an example would be `SELECT Name FROM EmployeeDatabase WHERE Department='Human Resources'` which would give me a new table with just those in the Human Resources department.  I want to ideally accomplish this with excel only.

Comment: Import your excel into access and proceed from there. The original error here is one that millions of businesses make; hiring someone who understands excel but not access and treats excel as a database even though it's the wrong tool for the job

Comment: Without sharing some sample data (you can replace confidential info with placeholders), describing exactly what you've tried and how those attempts don't fulfil your needs we can't understand your problem, therefore we're unable to give valid advice.

Comment: The staff who will be viewing the data don't have MS Access due to licencing costs.  I will put the data into an access db file and use excel to present it with DAO.  I cannot explain it in any more simple terms.  If what I've written cannot be understood without sample data then it probably isn't possible.  I'll just stick to the way I know.

Comment: @iShaymus,, using SQL commad needs VBA by record set method,, and filter data in usual way needs either Advance filter or Excel function and the sample data help me & others to justify the solution we are suppose to apply !!

Comment: @RajeshS It's quite simple.  Can you have two tables where the second table is data filtered from the first table. Without VBA and with the data being dynamic.  I can do it quite easily with VBA but I was hoping no to and maybe learn something new in the process.

Comment: @iShaymus,, okay now check my post and I'm sure is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to suggest method based on Excel Function, filters/extracts records from source Table to another.*

**Source Table:**

[image]

---

[image]

---

**How it works:**

- If criteria cells are blank then formula didn't returns record.
- Formula works for single as well as multiple criteria.

---

**Situation 1:**

[image]

**Situation 2:**

[image]

- Array formula in Cell`B31`:

`{=IFERROR(IF(AND(ISBLANK($B$27),ISBLANK($C$27),ISBLANK($D$27),ISBLANK($E$27),ISBLANK($F$27),ISBLANK($G$27),ISBLANK($H$27))," ",INDEX($B$2:$H$21,SMALL(IF(MMULT(($B$2:$H$21=$B$27:$H$27)*1,{1;1;1;1;1;1;1})=COUNTA($B$27:$H$27),MATCH(ROW($B$2:$B$21),ROW($B$2:$B$21)),""),ROWS($A$1:A1)),COLUMNS($A$1:A1))),"")}`

- Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill across.

---

- Key feature of this exercise is `MMULT` function.
- MMULT (Matrix Multiplication), returns the matrix product of two arrays.
- Column count of array1 equals to the Row count of array2.
- The array result contains same number of Rows as array1 as well as same number of Columns as array2.

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*